# Value returned from a script does not assigned to a variable declared in jenkins declarative pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am working on adding a jenkins Declarative pipeline for automation testing. In the test run stage i want to extract the failed tests from the log. i am using a groovy function for extracting the test result. this function is not a part of the jenkins pipeline. It is another script file. The function works fine and it build a string containing the failure details. Inside a pipeline stage i am calling this function and assinging the returned string to another variable. But when i echo the variable value it prints empty string.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yamlFile 'kubernetesPod.yml'
        }
    }
    environment{
        failure_msg = ""
    }
    stages {
        stage('Run Test') {
            steps {
                container('ansible') {
                    script {
                        def notify = load('src/TestResult.groovy')
                        def result = notify.extractTestResult("${WORKSPACE}/testreport.xml")
                        sh "${result}"
                        if (result != "") {
                            failure_msg = failure_msg + result
                        }
                    }

                }  
            }
        }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                sh 'echo Failure message.............${failure_msg}'
                }
        }
    }
}
```

here 'sh 'echo ${result}'' print empty string. But 'extractTestResult()' returns a non-empty string.

Also i am not able to use the environment variable 'failure_msg' in post section it return an error **'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: failure_msg for class: groovy.lang.Binding'**

can anyone please help me with this ?

EDIT:

> Even after i fixed the string interpolation, i was getting the same
>   error. That was because jenkins does not allow using 'sh' inside
>   docker container. there is an open bug ticket in [jenkins issue
>   board](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58657)

Comment: Can you please try if your issue disappears if you use the correct string interpolation (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) on your sh-command. Try: sh "${failure_msg}"

Comment: Another issue could be that the variable does not exist in the post-stage-scope because it was declared in the scope of the steps-block.

Comment: Agree with @mkemmerz. It's the incorrect string interpolation. In addition, `failure_msg` here is not being set as an environment variable, but Groovy global variable. The difference is that environment variables (`env.failure_msg`) are available to the sub shells called by the pipeline script whereas Groovy global variables are not. On using double quotes with `sh`, it is Groovy that interpolates the variable and not shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a global variable for holding the error message. My guess is that the variable is not existing in your scope.

```
def FAILURE_MSG // Global Variable

pipeline {
    ...
    stages {
        stage(...
            steps {
                container('ansible') {
                    script {
                        ...
                        if (result != "") {
                            FAILURE_MSG = FAILURE_MSG + result
                        }
                    }    
                }  
            }
        }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                sh "${FAILURE_MSG}" // Hint: Use correct String Interpolation
                }
        }
    }
}
```

(Similar SO question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063864/using-global-variables-in-jenkins-pipeline))