# How to define a variable in post section of pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to use some common value across different conditions in post section of pipeline hence I tried following -

**1.**

```
post {  
      script {
           def variable = "<some dynamic value here>"
      }
      failure{
           script{
                  "<use variable  here>"
           }
     }
     success{
          script{
                "<use variable  here>"
         }
    }
}
```

**2**

```
post {  
          def variable = "<some dynamic value here>"
          failure{
               script{
                      "<use variable  here>"
               }
         }
         success{
              script{
                    "<use variable  here>"
             }
        }
    }
```

But it results into compilation error.

Can you please suggest how I can declare a variable in `post` section which can be used across conditions?

Comment: You can find a solution (global variable) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972250/value-returned-from-a-script-does-not-assigned-to-a-variable-declared-in-jenkins/58972645#58972645

Comment: within a string that was surrounded by single quotes and had json I had to add one of my variables like this:  `''' +variablename+ '''`  I can't remember where I found this answer but I don't see this format anywhere else on the web when doing similar searches.  Yes, you need to include the 3 single quotes on either side, and yes you need to include the plus symbols, no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `always` condition which is [guaranteed to be executed before any other conditions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) like `success` or `failure`. If you want to store `String` value, you can use use `env` variable to store it (environment variable always casts given value to a string). Alternatively, you can define a global variable outside the `pipeline` and then initialize it with the expected dynamic value inside the `always` condition. Consider the following example:

```groovy
def someGlobalVar

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                echo "Test"
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            script {
                env.FOO = "bar"
                someGlobalVar = 23
            }
        }

        success {
            echo "FOO is ${env.FOO}"
            echo "someGlobalVar = ${someGlobalVar}"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Running on Jenkins in /home/wololock/.jenkins/workspace/pipeline-post-sections
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
Test
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
FOO is bar
[Pipeline] echo
someGlobalVar = 23
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```